# vector doesn't work with my class

Tags: c++, class, vector

Can anyone explain me what am I doing wrong:
I have a class `MClass` and `MClass2 (MClass : public MClass2 {})`, as follows:

```
vector <MClass> mdata;
MClass2 *Mbuff = new MClass2;
```

The following works

```
Mbuff->loadData(/*some data*/); //this works; I can print data from Mbuff
```

However, this does not:

```
mdata.push_back(*Mbuff); //this doesn't work... I can't print data from mdata
```

Why not?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! What language is this? I'm going to add a C++ tag, but I'm just guessing.

Comment: Did you create **Copy Constructor** for `MClass` I am guessing the data is not being copied to the internal instance of `MClass` that is being created by the `vector`. also it might be a better idea to use boost's `ptr_vector` like `boost::ptr_vector<MClass> mData;` that way you don't need to worry about the copy constructor and cleanup. You can then add data to it like `mData.push_back(new MClass2);`

Comment: Lookup "object slicing".

Answer (score 1):

If indeed `MClass` inherits from `MClass2`, as you seem to suggest by writing `MClass : public MClass2 {}`, then you cannot treat an `MClass2` object as an `MClass` object, but the other way around.

(Similarly, if you have `Class Dog : public Animal`, you can treat Dogs as Animals, but you can't treat Animals as Dogs.)

So, since `*Mbuff` is an `MClass2` object, you can't put it in a vector of `MClass` objects.

But you need to be  more specific about what you mean by "this doesn't work".